# Laravel x Flask - Client error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/run` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:

Tags: python, php, laravel, flask, guzzle

I have 2 systems that created from Laravel & Flask

Laravel - http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Flask - http://127.0.0.1:5000/

When I'm trying to send form data post request together with file from Laravel to Flask via Guzzle, I got this error message.

```
"""
Client error: `POST http://127.0.0.1:5000/run` resulted in a `400 BAD REQUEST` response:
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>The brows (truncated...)
"""
```

If using POSTMAN, no issue at all

[image]

Laravel code

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $options = [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name'     => 'file',
                        'contents' => file_get_contents(storage_path('app/public/config/'.$service->config, 'r' ))
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'     => 'service_id',
                        'contents' => $id
                    ],
                    [
                        'name'     => 'email',
                        'contents' => auth()->user()->email
                    ]
                ]
            ];
            $response = $client->post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/run', $options);
```

Flask code

```
@app.route('/run', methods=['POST'])
def run():
    service_id = request.form.get("service_id")
    email = request.form.get("email")
    file = request.files['file']
```

The error message happened because of the file. It exists but cant sent.

Update: I changed from `file_get_contents` into `fopen`. The client-side Flask successfully intercepted my request but on server side Laravel, still loading like never-ending story...

Comment: Try removing 'r' from storage_path call.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov If using fopen with 'r', no issue for client-side but server-side still loading (infinitely).